# Sqlite Crash libsqlite3.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_function669$$libsqlite3.dylib

Tags: ios, ios7, sqlite, frameworks

I am new for Developing Framework in iOS.

I have developed one framework using sqlite3 where I am doing all operations of that framework in background which is using

```
      dispatch_async(Queue, ^{

        [self syncWithServer];
  });
```

above code is written in syncToServer method which get called from application

I have added 8 method's to this framework which is as in FACADE Layer,so I can access it from my application,

like `[myFramework syncToServer]`

I have used SQlite as Framework modal(database) which is created programatically in iOS which is as follows

```
-(void)createDatabaseForFramework{

DBConnectionManager *connectionManager=[[DBConnectionManager alloc] init];
const char *databasePath = [[connectionManager getDatabasePath] UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(databasePath, &mDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    char *errorMessage;
    const char *createStatement = [createApplicationTableQuery UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_exec(mDatabase, applicationCreateStatement, NULL, NULL, &errorMessage)!= SQLITE_OK)
    {
         NSLog(@"errorMessage");                                                                                                   
    }
    sqlite3_close(mDatabase);
}}
```

**I am doing these things in my framework where catching some data and syncing to the server everything I am doing it in background**

even I have added all application state to framework where I am doing sync and storing data.

**When I am using this myFramework in my application and when I am coming from background state to foreground I am getting the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS which is as below**

```
* thread #53: tid = 0x185d3, 0x37f39c28 libsqlite3.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_function669$$libsqlite3.dylib + 16, queue = 'com.application.ApplicationStates, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe00001dc)
```

If i am missing anything or need to do something to overcome with this issue please let me know Thanks in advance

**Note***I have followed all necessary steps for sqlite and framework which is integrated in myApplication*

here are the (steps) details of above crash

1. Fetched data to sqlite from application(which is through myFramework)
2. I Locked the device(iPad).
3. again Unlocked the device and launched an application.
4. after above steps If I do some DB transactions which is with framework DB Iam getting above mentioned crash

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the 8 methods you have added are and what they do ?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco Thanks for reply, you need not to know about other functions, because I am getting this stuck with syncToServer call and reason is the sqlite where i have mentioned all details as above.

Comment: Do you finalize or reset your sqlite statement?

Comment: Having more of the crash log would be helpful.  The top part with exception codes and the whole stack frame of the crashed thread would be the parts that would be most helpful, but the whole crash log would be best.

Comment: @Don thanks for reply yes sqlite statements are finalised properly.

Comment: @WaltSellers thanks for Comment, I am executing steps in different dispatch queues,If I add all DB operations by maintaining single queue it will work. but can you please tell me,if is there another way with multiple queues so I can execute my DB operations efficiently.

Comment: @SandeepKhade Just curious, why aren't you using Core Data for this? You could write an `NSIncrementalStore` adapter which connects to the server. Core Data would be a lot easier to use, not to mention very reliable because Apple invests a lot of time and resources into keeping it robust.

Comment: Thanks @SamStigler for your suggestion, will try CD next time.